# Soy algo nuevo con base de datos y no se como hacer una consulta entre 2 tablas?

Tags: mysql

tabla usuario(id, name)
tabla socio(id, name, user_id)
Es una relacion manyToOne,un usuario tiene muchos socios pero un socio solo tiene un usuario.
Quiero mostrar una tabla en la que me muestre los datos de la tabla **socio** pero solo los datos que se relacionan con un **usuario** especifico.
Por ej.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esas 2 tablas quisiera poder hacer una consulta en la que me muestre una respuesta similar al de la tabla salida esperada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor si alguien podria ayudarme con esto le estoy muy agradecido. Saludos.

Hasta ahora solo logro mostrar todos los socios que tienen un usuario por lo que no me aparece en mi consulta el usuario4 por ejemplo, pero quiero que mi consulta solo muestre los socios de un usuario especifico

El codigo que intente por ahora es el siguiente

```
SELECT socio.id, socio.name, socio.user_id
FROM socio as s INNER JOIN usuario AS u ON (u.id = s.user_id)
WHERE u.is = s.user_id
```

Comment: utiliza los [joins](https://ingenieriadesoftware.es/tipos-sql-join-guia-referencia/)

Comment: Utiliza Joins como te han dicho, lee, aprende e intenta, si te complica mucho, muestra que has intentado para ayudarte.

Comment: Ya agregue el codigo que intente

Comment: agrega u.name a tu select y listo.... ;)

Comment: y el where sobra....

Comment: Una duda : En el where , quien es "p" ? (p.user_id)

Comment: @elierickdevelopment Tal y como dice gbianchi, este sobra además de estar implementado. p no existe en ningún lado. Por eso le consultaba que le retornaba la consulta, pero al parecer nunca notó el error.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración estimado @Excorpion , pensé que me perdía de algo XD.

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi me ayudo eso y me equivoque al transcribir en lugar de p tenia q colocar s lo siento

Comment: ya edite el error y gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

en la consulta el where te esta sobrando, te recomiendo que revises su funcionamiento en cuanto a tu problema la consulta lo mas sencillo seria:

```
SELECT socio.id, socio.name, u.user_name
FROM socio as s INNER JOIN usuario AS u
```

Comment: a tu join le falta la condicion de join...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te estas haciendo un lio con los alias (as), lo que siempre me han dicho a mi a la hora de resolver ejercicios, problemas, o cualquier cosa en referencia a la programación es a dividir el problema en pequeños problemas y solucionar por partes.

Te recomiendo que de primeras quites los AS, y luego comiences desde el SELECT y le digas que quieres añadir de cada tablas, según lo que veo que quieres mostrar es el "usuario.id", "socio.name" y "usuario.name".

El INNER JOIN parece que esta bien pero el WHERE creo que te sobra, a no ser que quieras buscar un id, usuario.name, o socio.name en particular que entonces usarías WHERE socio.name = 'socio3' y entonces te pasaría solo los datos del socio3.

Por ultimo en primer lugar te recomiendo es que hagas 2000 pruebas, cambies todo y veas que pasa cada vez que vas cambiado cosas para saber que hace cada una de ellas, y ya si por ultimo no consigues avanzar busques ayuda en general de como se usa algo y no de un ejercicio en particular.

Espero haber ayudado, un saludo.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias tomare en cuenta el consejo